# > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. Unable to find git in your PATH

Tags: android, flutter, dart

> Task : app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
> Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
> Unable to find git in your PATH.

When I go to debug it gives this error, I already changed the path but it didn't solve it, I tried several alternatives but none worked

[Path system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTPaE.png)

Comment: did  you install git?

Comment: yes the latest version

Comment: Have you included it in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes, it's in the image what I have in the path variable